# Comparing dates in awk shell

Tags: shell, awk, grep

Hello I'm trying to make a script to search for specific info from a file and print it. My case is this : I have a file in the format of : `id|lastname|firstname|birthday|` . I want to call the script and given a date argument and the file to make it show me all the "people" born after the date I've given.
 Let me show you my code :

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in 
--born-since )
d=($2 +%F); # this one puts the date I've given into the variable d
grep -vE '^#' $4 | awk -F "|" ' $4 >= $d '
;;
esac
```

I call this script in the form of :

```
./script --born-since <date> -f <file>
```

Point is it's not doing what I want it to do. I prints wrong results.
For example in a file with 4 dates ( 1989-12-03,1984-02-18,1988-10-14,1980-02-02), given the date of 1985-05-13 it prints only the person with date 1984-02-18 which is incorrect.
It's probably comparing something else and not the date. Any advice ?

Comment: yeah my bad,it's wrong, it's just too many different  results from different entries, therefore I got a bit confused, editing

Comment: post a few input lines will all fields

Answer (score 1):

With single **awk** process:

```
awk -v d="1985-09-09" -F'|' '$4 >= d' file
```

Comment: This works, although for dates equal it doesn't. Thank you though since I can try and experiment around that! Is it possible to compare for greater and less (for 2 different dates of course) in a single command?)

Comment: @DimitrisDelis, yes, it's possible